# Is it possible to let the "ajaxed" page use the caller's script?

Tags: ajax, external

I really do not know how to put this on the proper words, but the idea is the following:

I want to call a page through jQuery's load(), which contains a carousel's code.

Since on the main page I have included the carousel's script (in this case jQ Carousel) I would like to use the code I have included instead of calling it back from the "ajaxed" page.

Is it possible?
Thanks a lot people!

---

Just in case this is the script of my second carousel.

I don't know if I'm doing it right, and is breaking because it does not default as the $carousel variable since the other carousel is using it as a Global variable and not a specific function one.

http://5509.github.com/jq.carousel/

```
$carousel_pl = $('#carousel_pl').carousel({
    loop:false,
    group: 6,
    start:1,
    indicator:true
}) 
$prev_pl = $('#min_'),
$next_pl = $('#plus_'),
set_state_2_2 = function() {
    var state_2 = $carousel_pl.carousel('getMoveState');
    switch ( state_2 ) {
        case 'min':
            $prev_pl.prop('disabled', 'disabled');
            $next_pl.prop('disabled', '');
            break;
        case 'max':
            $prev_pl.prop('disabled', '');
            $next_pl.prop('disabled', 'disabled');
            break;
        case true:
            $prev_pl.prop('disabled', '');
            $next_pl.prop('disabled', '');
            break;
        default:
            $prev_pl.prop('disabled', 'disabled');
            $next_pl.prop('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
};
$('#min_').on('click', function(ev) {
    $carousel_pl.carousel('prev');
});
$('#plus_').on('click', function(ev) {
    $carousel_pl.carousel('next');
});
$carousel_pl.carousel('reset');
$carousel_pl.carousel('refresh');
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, fixed my own problem!

**It does work!**

The problem was that I missed a DIV and the code didn't work.